# regex failing for double value

Tags: java, regex

```
Double dbl = 0.003;
String str = dbl.toString();

str.matches("^\\d{1,7}\\.?\\d{1,3}$");
```

`regex` returns `false`.

`str` value returns as **0.0030**

Regex is failing which is different from Float problem.

Comment: That question was marked as duplicate of some other issue and in comment someone mentioned that was not duplicate. This is not related to Float problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed behaving correctly (the regex bit I mean). You've limited the digits to three following the decimal and you're giving it four.

I'd suggest either modifying the string to remove trailing zeros (assuming they're after a decimal point of course), or changing the regex to make it suitable.

The former can be done with something like:

```
s = s.replaceFirst("(\\.\\d+)0+$", "$1").replaceFirst("\\.0+$", ".0");
```

The latter involves adding zeros to the end of the regex:

```
str.matches("^\\d{1,7}\\.?\\d{1,3}0*$");
```

You may also want to consider putting the decimal and fractional digits into a group, regardless of which method you choose. In other words, something like:

```
    str.matches("^\\d{1,7}(\\.\\d{1,3})?$");
```

As it stands now, that regex will also accept a 10-digit integral number.

Comment: For now I am using replaceFirst as you suggested which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642883/double-tostring-or-string-valufof-not-returning-right-value), you are just running into the known bug-

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4428022

*0050* is not 3-character long. Hence, *false*. You can try updating your JDK environment or use [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html). In my JDK7, I get-

> 0.005
>
> true

Comment: I got this but when value is 0.0052 still I get the output as 0.005

Comment: I confirmed that the behavior in the question is only in Java 6 and prior, and the bug is fixed in Java 7.

Comment: @nhahtdh prior to 7.

Comment: I am using JDK6 and cannot upgrade to 7 as it is not just me, as it should work in prod as well which they will not upgrade to JDK7